# предупреждение valgrind : "invalid read of size..." , "Syscall param points to unaddressable byte(s)"

Tags: c++, valgrind, syscall

Имеется следующий код (C++):

```
 struct command
{
    vector<char*> argv;
    char* file_input;
    char* file_output;
 
    string leksema;
 
    command* follow_pipe;
 
 
    command() {
        file_input = file_output = 0;
        follow_pipe = 0;
    }
 
    ~command() {
        if (this->follow_pipe != nullptr )
            delete this->follow_pipe;
    }
};
 
void pipe_run (command* ptr) {
    pid_t pid, wpid;
    int pfd[2], input, status;
    bool first = true;
    while (ptr != nullptr ) {
        pipe(pfd);
        if (!(pid = fork())) {
            if (!first) {
                dup2(input, 0);
                close(input);
            }
            if ( ptr->follow_pipe != nullptr )
                dup2(pfd[1], 1);
            close(pfd[0]);
            close(pfd[1]);
            if ( ptr->file_input )
                change_in (ptr->file_input );
            if ( ptr->file_output )
                change_out (ptr->file_output );
            execvp( ptr->argv[0], &ptr->argv[0]);
            cerr<<"eexec_vp"<<'\n';
        }
        if (!first)
            close(input);
        close(pfd[1]);
        input = pfd[0];
        do {
            wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
        first = false;
        ptr = ptr->follow_pipe;
    }
}
```

По факту, этот код эмуляция конвейера shell. Указатель ptr это фактически указатель на вершину связанного списка, ptr->follow_pipe -- указатель на следующую команду в конвейере. При запуске под valgring выдается предупреждение: "invalid read size of ", " Syscall param execve(argv[i]) points to unaddressable byte(s)"с ссылкой на строчку системного вызова execvp.

Объясните пожалуйста, на что же ругается valgrind и как это исправить.

update : добавил "перелив" vector<char*> -> char** -- проблему не решило:

```
struct command
{
    vector<char*> argv;
    char* file_input;
    char* file_output;

    string leksema;

    command* follow_pipe;


    command() {
        file_input = file_output = 0;
        follow_pipe = 0;
    }

    ~command() {
        if (this->follow_pipe != nullptr )
            delete this->follow_pipe;
    }
};

void pipe_run (command* ptr) {
    pid_t pid, wpid;
    int pfd[2], input, status;
    bool first = true;
    while (ptr != nullptr ) {
        pipe(pfd);
        if (!(pid = fork())) {
            if (!first) {
                dup2(input, 0);
                close(input);
            }
            if ( ptr->follow_pipe != nullptr )
                dup2(pfd[1], 1);
            close(pfd[0]);
            close(pfd[1]);
            if ( ptr->file_input )
                change_in (ptr->file_input );
            if ( ptr->file_output )
                change_out (ptr->file_output );
            if ( ptr->argv.size() > 0 ) {
                char** temp = new char*[ptr->argv.size()];
                for ( int i = 0; i < ptr->argv.size(); ++i )
                    temp[i] = ptr->argv[i];
                execvp(temp[0], temp);
            }
        }
        if (!first)
            close(input);
        close(pfd[1]);
        input = pfd[0];
        do {
            wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
        first = false;
        ptr = ptr->follow_pipe;
    }
}
```

update2: добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример (конвейер был замен на просто вызов функции, однако проблема все та же):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct command
{
    vector<char*> argv;

    string leksema;

    ~command() {
    }
};

pid_t pid_run;

void command_run ( command*  pCmd) {
    execvp(pCmd->argv[0], &pCmd->argv[0]);
}

pair<string, int> extract_word (int idx, string & line) {
    int ptr = idx;
    string ans;
    while ( line[ptr] == ' ' || line[ptr] == '\t')
        ++ptr;
    while ( !(line[ptr] == ' ' || line[ptr] == '\t' || line[ptr] == '\n' || line[ptr] == '\000' ) ) {
        ans.push_back(line[ptr]);
        ++ptr;
    }
    return make_pair(ans, ptr+1 -idx);
}

void extract_command ( command* pCmd , int  idx, string & line) {
    vector<string> ARG;
    string file_in, file_out;

    pair<string, int> word;

    while ( idx < line.size() ) {
        switch ( line[idx]  ) {
        case ' ' : ++idx; break;
        case '\t' : ++idx; break;
        case '-' : word = extract_word(idx, line);
            ARG.push_back(word.first);
            idx +=word.second;
            break;
        default : word = extract_word(idx, line);
                 idx += word.second;
                 ARG.push_back(word.first);
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARG.size(); i++)
       pCmd->argv.push_back((char *)ARG[i].c_str());
    pCmd->argv.push_back(nullptr);
    return;
}


int main () {
    string s ;
    getline(cin, s);
    command* temp = new command;
    extract_command (temp, 0,  s);
    command* temp_copy = temp;
    command_run ( temp );
    delete temp_copy;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: скорей всего он ругается на неверно составленный список `argv`... вангую, что забыл завершающий `NULL`...

Comment: execvp( ptr->argv[0], &ptr->argv[0]); я думаю ему не нравится, что vector<char*> пытаешься подсунуть как массив const char* argv[], вектор это связный список в памяти, следующий элемент необязательно может идти сразу за текущим, и он не обязательно кончается нолем. попробуй использовать вместо этого список, или делай итерацию по вектору дважды, сначала для поиска размера и выделения нужного буфера, и потом для копирования, перед вызовом выделяй массив по размеру списка, копируй туда аргументы и передавай exec'у.

Comment: @Fat-Zer , не push_back-нуть NULL я точно не забыл, проблема в другом.

Comment: @Yakov, если я Вас правильно понял, то поменял код (см. обновленный вопрос), но это не решило проблему.

Comment: @Yakov, похоже ты перепутал `vector` с `list`'ом...

Comment: @Ilya, почти наверняка неправильно конструируешь `argv`... если `NULL` в конец добавил, то снова вангую, что пихаешь туда указатель на временную строку, которая к моменту `exec()` уже уничтожена... в общем [mcve] в студию...

Comment: попробуйте все аргументы функции argv заменить строкой с пробелом в качестве разделителя. вместо отдельных значений в массиве, и str.c_str() уже скормить exec'u может тогда от вас валгринд отстанет. вы уверены что ваши строки все NULL-treminated? я в коде не видел memset или buffer[len+1]=0; при "копировании". вы просто сделали массив указателей, но непонятно есть ли в конце каждого из этих  указателей NULL -> \0. может это валгринду и не нравится.

Comment: Функции execle() и execvpe() позволяют вызывающему назначить окружение исполняемой программе через параметр envp. Аргумент envp является массивом указателей на строки (завершающиеся null), он должен заканчиваться указателем null. Остальные функции извлекают окружение для нового образа процесса из внешней переменной environ вызвавшего процесса.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sDudm5rp попробуй так переделать.

Comment: @Fat-Zer , добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Yakov , добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример, к сожалению Ваш код, так же дает то же предупреждение valgrind

Comment: @Ilya, как и говорил, ты в `extract_command` создаёшь строки и сохраняешь указатели на них... при выходе из функции эти строки уничтожаются и указатели продолжают указывать на память, которая освобождена и в любой момент может быть занята чем-то другим... об этом valgrind и говорит...

Comment: я ваш пример скомпилировал, валгринд сказал все ок. может я не с теми опциями его запускаю?

Comment: @Yakov , у меня valgrind выдает ошибки: я использовал и valgrind, запущенный и из терминала линукс и valgrind, встроенный в qtcreator

Comment: я даун, назвал приложение выходное тест)) запускаю ошибок нет. пока не вспомнил, что есть стандартная утилита test, и еще думаю чего он ввод у меня не спрашивает. запустил ./test заматерился валгринд. исправил пару строк  static vector<string> ARG;ARG.clear(); - вроде перестал. так что @Fat-Zer прав у тебя в этом проблема была.

Comment: в общем более "правильный" вариант в деструктор добавить     `~command() {
  for(int i=0;i<argv.size();i++)
   if(argv[i])
    free(argv[i]);
    }`  а вставку элемента обернуть в strdup() `pCmd->argv.push_back((char *)strdup(ARG[i].c_str()));`